# Highcharts: How can I make the range attribute work?

Tags: highcharts

I have problems to get the range attribute in highcharts to work. As you can see in the demo on https://jsfiddle.net/o64p781e/2/ four series of data are shown. The range attribute should restrict the amount to three but doesn't.

```
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/947ed489d6/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/947ed489d6/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/947ed489d6/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="width__full startshow"></div>
let chart1 = Highcharts.chart('test', {
data: {
    googleAPIKey: 'AIzaSyBjEEkDaezD0xEyJLL65_FNHGdH5yoMCQU',
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1PGxJT_RKeJBC9XncgdmRGreig4luEsqPR55dvScTtlI',
    googleSpreadsheetRange: "'test'",

        range: "test!A1:D5",
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
    error: console.error,
},
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties like `range` are not used by Highcharts. You need to specify the rule in `googleSpreadsheetRange`:

```
    data: {
        ...,
        googleSpreadsheetRange: "test!A1:D5"
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4k3aehps/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.googleSpreadsheetRange